# The right way to change Apache root directory outside /var/www/

Tags: linux, apache, google-compute-engine

**Intro**

I have added a disk to my instance on Google Cloud with the goal to run my website files on this disk. I formatted and mounted the disk following this Google Cloud documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

After finishing this tutorial you have a directory `/mnt/disks/appdata/` which is ready to write files to.

**What I have tried first**

I want to use this directory `/mnt/disks/appdata/` as root directory, so I added the following lines to my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file.

```
<Directory /mnt/disks/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>

...

DocumentRoot /mnt/disks/appdata
```

But after restarting my apache server and visiting my website I got a 404 error.

**How I have fixed the problem, but don't know if it is the right way**

To fix this problem I have added the following lines to my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

```
<Directory /mnt/disks/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This works, but I don't know if it is the best option to add this lines to the apache2.conf file, because the documentation in the apache2.conf file says:

> It does not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share
>   and /var/www. The former is used by web applications packaged in
>   Debian, the latter may be used for local directories served by the web
>   server. If your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv
>   you must allow access here, or in any related virtual host.

Comment: What if you do not change your root, but instead create a symlink to `/mnt/disks/appdata` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I am not familiar with symlinks. In which file(s) should I place this?

Comment: @IVOGELOV in my .htaccess file?

Comment: You have `Options FollowSymLinks`

Comment: A symbolic link is like a shortcut - you make an alias (pseudoname) at one place of the file system, which points to another file / directory. For explanation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link. You have `Options FollowSymLinks` - which implies it may be possible to create a symlink called `/var/www/mysite/mylink` and pointing to `/mnt/disks/appdata/mydestination` (you should try).

Comment: @IVOGELOV Okay, thanks for your explanation. I will try!